# Pure Mathematics reference books at grade 12/undergraduate level

Tags: calculus, matrices, reference-request, complex-numbers, book-recommendation

I've just entered 11th grade, and I'm taking up A-Level Further Math. The Pure Math part of this syllabus covers polynomials, various graphs, calculus (about AP level), matrices, complex numbers (de Moivre's theorem, etc.). There are no official books for the syllabus right now, so I'm looking for recommendations for Pure Mathematics books at a 12th grade/university level. If possible, I'm also looking to learn beyond the syllabus, so more advanced books would also be appreciated, but preferably ones that take some time to explain the basics as well.

 Edit- 
 I'm also looking for books with matrices being done in detail, (from the basics to eigenvalues, matrix ranks etc)

Comment: I liked https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aTtlRgAACAAJ and its second volume when we used them. Has some interesting extra stuff, and plenty of exercises (some with answers).

Comment: I'm actually looking for a book which covers matrices more extensively, does this book cover slightly more advanced concepts like matrice ranks and eigenvectors?

Comment: @tiredandsarcastic, you should tell me your country in order to tell you the local author books because std. books took a lot time and they are mostly abstract

Comment: My suggestion would be to consider getting a couple of books if you are interested in varying topics. For topics such as eigenvalues, matrices, rank, etc, probably your best best (In my opinion) would be to get an introductory book to Linear Algebra

Comment: I don't think there will be a single book covering linear algebra (matrices)  and calculus. You can use Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics* for calculus since it is especially suitable for students of age 16 years or so. For linear algebra I used the book by Hoffman and Kunze. Anyway the introductory parts of linear algebra are not much difficult and the proofs are easy and you should not have problems following them from any book.